# Using string enum value in HTML component in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Imagine the following string enum, which is defined in a component.ts:

```js
export enum SortType {
 Date = 'date',
}
```

I want to use the value of the enum in the corresponding HTML-component: `<th mat-sort-header=??? >`

Something like that: `<th mat-sort-header='SortType.Date' >`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the value of imported Enum in a class property.

```
import { SortType } from '.....path'

@component({data})
export class YourComponent  {
  sortEnum = SortType;
}
```

Use in your HTML

```
<th mat-sort-header="{{sortEnum.Date}}" >.
```

Comment: That brings me the exact same string.
I have a console.log(sort.active) in the sort-function of mat-sort (`matSort (matSortChange)="sort($event)`).
In this case it shows me 'sortEnum.Date' instead of 'date'

Comment: @Link I am sorry, misssed the interpolation

Answer (score 1):

In ts create a class property  as public sortEnum=SortType and access in html

```
public sortEnum=SortType
```